# Make function execution verbose by verbose-__enter__-like mechanism

Tags: python

I want to make a class' functions verbose without adding logging / prints in each one.

As an example I created a verbose class:

```
In [2]: class Verbose(object): 
   ...:     def __init__(self, name='default name'): 
   ...:         self._name = name 
   ...:     def __enter__(self, *a, **kw): 
   ...:         print('Entering <{}>'.format(self._name)) 
   ...:     def __exit__(self, *a, **kw): 
   ...:         print ('Exiting <{}>'.format(self._name)) 
In [5]: with Verbose('hi'): 
   ...:     pass 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                  
Entering <hi>
Exiting <hi>
```

This is really helpful in the logs, as I can see each `with` I used. However, my code is full of methods, and I want a sort of template function, that each function would "inherit" (is that even possible in Python? function inheritance?) that would be verbose.

I'm thinking of sort of a super-class for functions, that I can override methods such as `on-call` and `on-exit`. Is that possible?

How I imagine it will look at the end:

```
Class Foo(object):
    def x(self):
       print ('doing things...')

Foo().x()
... <Foo.x> was called
... doing things
... <Foo.x> has finished
```

Comment: probably with a decorator

Comment: This would make me decorate each function, I'm hoping to overload the function object, if it is possible

Comment: I found a good duplicate. tested the accepted answer. Does exactly what you want